# WordPress Custom Content Type Manager Only Updates Once

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Custom Content Type Manager plugin to create a media field for posts. When I upload or choose media with it, it works fine the first time I update my post. But when I try to upload a different file or remove a file, it looks like it is working until I press update. Then it will just show the media I uploaded the first time. I can't figure out why it won't update.  I tried removing the field from the database and recreating the field, but the problem doesn't go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered this problem was only happening when I used cctm with wp e-commerce.  There is some sort of conflict between cctm and wp e-commerce as I found from here: https://code.google.com/p/wordpress-custom-content-type-manager/issues/detail?id=312
I found another plugin called "wp e-commerce custom fields" which worked well.